# How to fix error "reference to entity "orderby" must end with the ';' delimiter"?

Tags: javascript, html

I tried to give slider to show recent posts from my blog posts. I have placed the below script but getting:

> The reference to entity "orderby" must end with the ';' delimiter

Here is my code:

```
<script>
document.write(" <script src='\"/feeds/posts/default?max-results=5&orderby=published&alt=json-in-script&callback=showrecentposts6\"'><\/script>");
</script>
```

Comment: can you please show your complete code inside the script

Comment: Why are you using `document.write`?  Why not just include a `<script>` tag for `/feeds/posts/default?...`?

Answer (score 2):

`&` is a special character in [HTML](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#character-references):

> Character references must start with a U+0026 AMPERSAND character (&).

Therefore, when you just want `&`, you should escape it as

```html
&amp;
```

---

However, you should not get that error. [The parser should tolerate](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#character-reference-in-data-state) `&` instead of `&amp;` when it's not possible to consume a character reference:

> Attempt to consume a character reference, with no additional allowed
>   character.
>
> If nothing is returned, emit a U+0026 AMPERSAND character (&) token.

[It would really be an error in XML](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#syntax):

> The ampersand character (&) and the left angle bracket (<) MUST NOT
>   appear in their literal form, except when used as markup delimiters,
>   or within a comment, a processing instruction, or a CDATA section.

However, [you can't use `document.write` in XML](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#document.write()):

> If the method was invoked on an XML document, throw an
>   InvalidStateError exception and abort these steps.